# Extract 'linguistically significant' characters from an RTF file

Tags: objective-c, text, wrapper, nsdata, rtf

I have written a Mac app that cross references various input text and RTF files to produce output files.  Part of that app reads in these files and extracts the 'linguistically significant' characters from either TXT or RTF files and releases them for further processing.

I am using the following method for this.  It works fine but I am wondering if perhaps I am either taking the long way around or doing something totally unnecessary.

```
  inputdatafile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: fullpath encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

   // test rtf wrapper code right here //
   inputdataNSData=[inputdatafile dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   wrapper = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initRegularFileWithContents:inputdataNSData];
   rtfData = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
           initWithRTF:[wrapper regularFileContents] documentAttributes:nil]; 
   inputdatafilefromrtf = [rtfData string];
   if (inputdatafilefromrtf) {
      inputdatafile = [NSMutableString stringWithString:inputdatafilefromrtf];};
```

inputdatafile is loaded with the contents of a file.  The program does not know what sort of text file it is and tries to see if it is RTF.  If so, it extracts the contents of the file for further processing.  If not, it assumes it is straight text and uses that.

It is possible that this is working totally accidentally and needs to be updated or perhaps there are better ways to do this.

Any thoughts that anybody has out there would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try identifying the type of file using RTFs [magic number](http://opensource.apple.com/source/file/file-44/file/magic/Magdir/rtf) like the unix command **[file](http://opensource.apple.com/source/file/file-44/)** does, or you could use a library like [libenca](http://gitorious.org/enca).

Here's a general explanation of file parsing and [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number).

Comment: Thanks but I'm not thinking either of those alternatives works much better than what I accidentally cobbled together above.